# List of current user objects in Django ListView

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-generic-views

I want to render list of all objects on my template, for which their author is the currently logged in user. I passed the username of current user to `url.py`:

```
<a href="{% url 'myscenarios' user.username %}">My List</a>
```

My urls.py:

```
path('myscenarios/<str:username>/', MyScenarioListView.as_view(), name='myscenarios'),
```

My question is how to build the queryset in `views.py` and what to type in template block in my html?

```
class MyScenarioListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Scenario
    template_name = 'testmanager/myscenarios.html'
    context_object_name = 'myscenarios'
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Scenario.objects.filter(scenarioAuthor = user).order_by('-date_posted')
```

What code should I type in my `myscenarios.html` file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to render list of all objects on my template, which their author is current logged user.

Then you should *not* encode the user in the path, since a "hacker" can then simply change the URL to see the items belonging to a different user.

You can make use of `self.request.user` here. The path thus looks like:

```
path('myscenarios/', MyScenarioListView.as_view(), name='myscenarios'),
```

and in the view, we use:

```
class MyScenarioListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Scenario
    template_name = 'testmanager/myscenarios.html'
    context_object_name = 'myscenarios'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Scenario.objects.filter(
            scenarioAuthor=self.request.user
        ).order_by('-date_posted')
```

It will pass the `Scenarios` as `myscenarios` to the template, so you can render this with:

```
{% for scenario in myscenarios %}
     {{ scenario }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you also tell how can one use the queryset=  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#viewing-subsets-of-objects to accomplish the same?

Comment: @VisheshMangla: you don't since that queryset has no access to `self` and thus can not find out the logged in user.

Comment: Yeah, I was too thinking it wouldn't be possible without the self. Thanks @WillemVanOnsem !.